# AKKA gRPC - Detect stream client crash at server

Tags: akka-grpc

I am connecting to AKKA GRPC Stream server to get the stream of messages. When the client dies/crashes for some reasons, not finding a way to detect at Server.

Is there any ErrorHandler/Callback register to get to know the client crashed?